# Shortcut for "git bisect" applying a rebase on each bisect point?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-bisect

While I worked on my `feature` branch, the `ci` branch has run forward. When I rebase my `feature` onto `ci`, tests fail. I'd like to find the commit(s) in `ci` after which my branch started failing.

I can write a script which rebases the `feature`, runs the tests, and then resets the branch back to the point before the rebase. Then, it can be used with `git bisect run <this script>`. But as this looks like a pattern, is there a ready-made command for it?

Comment: No, there is not. You will have to rebase, then run git bisect, find the faulty commit, then reset back and figure out which commit this is in your original branch. You could always create your own command for this, but due to the nature of the interactive process of git bisect, it might be a bit of code necessary.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen what you write is **not** what I need. As the question says, I'm looking for the commit **in the branch onto which I'm rebasing** which has caused **tests of my branch** to fail.

Comment: I understand now, and no, there is no such built-in command or script.

Comment: Rather than using `git rebase` (which alters a branch label) you can use `git cherry-pick` on the detached HEAD. Or, you can create a temporary branch name for rebase to modify so that there's nothing you need to put back. But: no, there's nothing built in for this.

Comment: I also think this question needs to consider whether or not a faulty commit was introduced on `ci` or on `feature`. You can't really say. Maybe the feature branch introduced the breakage (which simply was not visible before the rebase, but still there)